# Calculating previous end of the quarter month and year in UNIX BASH

Tags: bash, unix

I am very new to Unix and need help with calculating previous end of the quarter month and year in UNIX Bash

Eg:-
If today's date is **2021-05-11**, the output needs to be **032021** (March 2021)
IF today's date is **2021-01-31**, the output needs to be **122020** (Dec 2020)

I did try with case statement and is working as expected.

```
m=$(date +%m)
y=$(date +%Y)

if [ $m -ge 1 -a $m -le 3 ]; then
     prev_qtr_mon=12
     prev_qtr_yr=`expr $y - 1`
elif [ $m -ge 4 -a $m -le 6 ]; then
     prev_qtr_mon=03
     prev_qtr_yr=$y
elif [ $m -ge 7 -a $m -le 9 ]; then
     prev_qtr_mon=06
     prev_qtr_yr=$y
elif [ $m -ge 10 -a $m -le 12 ]; then
     prev_qtr_mon=09
     prev_qtr_yr=$y
fi
echo ${prev_qtr_mon}
echo ${prev_qtr_yr}
acct_dt=${prev_qtr_mon}${prev_qtr_yr}
echo ${acct_dt}
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this instead of big case statement? Can you please help?

Comment: Just wondering: why do you want to do that in bash?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more a question about mathematics than about programming. If your month is stored on `m`, as in your example code, the statement

```
((quartnum=M/4))
```

gives you on `quartnum` a number from 0 to 3, where 0 is the first quarter and 3 the last. This is the quarter where m actually is in.

The **previous** quarter is then one less or 3 more (depending on how you like to see it), and you have to ajust for the wrap-around at the year border. I would do +3 instead of -1 to avoid modulo-calculation with negative numbers:

```
((prevquartnum=(quartnum+3)%4))
```

To map the quarters to a month, you could use a not very elegant, but simple table:

```
quartmonth=(3 6 9 12)
```

This states that the first quarter (i.e. prevquartnum 0) is associated with March, the second quarter with June and so on. You now get the desired month by `${quartmonth[$prevquartnum]}`

I would handle the year with a simple `if`: If `m` is 3 or less, you have to subtract 1 from the year. Otherwise it is simply the current year.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it with arithmetic expression like `((m >= 1 && m <= 3))` for readability and leave it as it is - it's clear, readable, easy to maintain, has no bugs. I would also add error handling. Do not use `expr` - use `$((...))`. Prefer `$(..)` over backticks `...`. Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net . Except for stylistic issues, I would leave the logic as it is.

You could write:

```
if ((m <= 3)); then
     prev_qtr_mon=12
     prev_qtr_yr=$((y - 1))
elif ((m <= 6)); then
     prev_qtr_mon=03
     prev_qtr_yr=$y
elif ((m <= 9)); then
     prev_qtr_mon=06
     prev_qtr_yr=$y
elif ((m <= 12)); then
     prev_qtr_mon=09
     prev_qtr_yr=$y
fi
```

If you know that `m <= something` is not true, that means that you know that `m > something` or `m >= something + 1`, as `m` is an integer.

Anyway: aligning up an expression to `3` boundary is done with adding `3 - 1` and divide and multiply by `3` - research how to do "ALIGN_UP" in C language, it's exactly the same method. As for `prev_qtr_yr` that is a simple if - I used that result of `<=` is equal to `1` or `0` below.

```
prev_qtr_mon=$( printf "%02d" "$(( tmp=(m + 2)/3*3, tmp?tmp*3:12 ))" )
prev_qtr_yr=$(( y - (m <= 3) ))
```

Comment: prev_qtr_mon=$( printf "%02d" "$(( (m + 2)/3*3 ))" ) gives me end of current quarter. I was looking for previous quarter. Eg:- if current date is may, june, july, need 03 and if month is jan, feb, mar then 12 + previous year. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Ie. the code is convoluted and harder to understand, harder to write and may cause bugs. Just use the `elif` tree, it's clear readable and works, and took you 1 min to write.